# Emulating bash's [ctrl]-l, **refreshing**

Tags: python, linux, bash, refresh, screen

I need a Python code snippet, that emulates Bash's clear-screen for **refreshing** the screen if it's messed up.

I need to use it in Bash, not in the Python interpreter.

Comment: You need a python snippet you can run in bash and not in a python interpreter? Can you clarify?

Comment: Exactly, because I need it in another program, that can source Python files. It's the same like the key strokes `ctrl-l` I'm seeking for wich I need to append on a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to clear the terminal's screen in python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('clear')
```

And in bash, you simply have to type `clear` in the terminal.

Comment: In `bash` or running `screen` the screen will be **refreshed** with `ctrl-l` if it's messed up. That's what I'm looking for, not for clearing the screen. The code snippet in Python I would like to use within another program, that also takes the refreshing command as bash or screen.

Comment: No, in bash the screen will be cleared with ctrl+L. Are you thinking of e.g. `nano`, `irssi` or other curses programs that use `Ctrl+L` to redraw themselves? Bash does not handle this.